# The dimension of spacetime in GR

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

In SR the 4-divergence of the 4-position gives the dimension of spacetime.

What is the dimension of spacetime in GR, i. e, The covariant divergence of the covariant position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In General Relativity, the dimension of spacetime is 4 but there is no such thing as a covariant 4-position. If there were, its covariant divergence would be not be a scalar; you have to take the covariant divergence of a *contra*variant vector to get a scalar.

Comment: Is $x_\nu$ not a covariant 4-position? I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: @Charlie In GR, coordinates themselves don’t transform covariantly or contravariantly. However, coordinate differentials $dx^\mu$ transform contravariantly, and $\partial_\mu=\partial/\partial x^\mu$ transforms covariantly.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you @G.Smith.